# Download TikTok video without watermark using Python and TiktokApi

Tags: python, video, download, tiktok

I am trying to download a TikTok video without the watermark based on the link, and I am using the TiktokApi package for this, but I am getting some exceptions when trying 2 different versions :

```
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi


api = TikTokApi()
url = 'TIKTOK_URL_HERE'
video_bytes = api.get_video_no_watermark(url)

with open("nature.mp4", 'wb') as output:
    output.write(video_bytes)
```

With 5.2.2/Latest version I got :

```
AttributeError: 'TikTokApi' object has no attribute 'get_video_no_watermark'
```

And when downgrading to 4.1.0, it tells that the method is deprecated :

```
Exception: Deprecated method, TikTok fixed this.
```

I already run this install :

```
python -m playwright install
```

If anyone has a solution for this, or maybe another package that will do the job?

Comment: I'm not expert in tiktok, but "TikTok fixed this" sounds a lot like TikTok simply doesn't offer watermark-free downloads anymore, and what you want is impossible. It would make sense – the kinds of things posted to TikTok are *optimized* for being re-shareable and there's going to be a lot of leeching, useless sites that just try to download stuff and claim it as their own; which is in direct conflict with a) copyright everywhere and b) TikTok's commercial interests.

Comment: Yeah, that seems logical to me. Thank you for the explanation